# Give id in decimal SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `content_details` and want to print id in decimal like this:

```
id     contents
1.1    vegetarian
1.2    non-vegetarian
```

I have used this query to

```
ALTER TABLE content_details
ADD COLUMN id decimal(4,2)
```

then used this to save data in column

```
ALTER TABLE content_details
ADD id = 1.1
WHERE contents_details= 'vegetarian'
```

But getting error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1.1 WHERE contents_details= 'vegetarian'' at line 2

Comment: You can't just make up commands and try them. Did you consult the documentation on how [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) works? What you're doing here is the equivalent of `ALTER TABLE COMPUTER ADD STUFF TO MY DATABASE THANKS`

Comment: I am sorry i am just a newbie. i have read it somewhere so used his command

Comment: Also worth noting having a `DECIMAL` ID-type column is usually nothing but trouble. Does this go `1.1`..`1.9` and then `1.10` or does it flip to `2.0`?

Comment: I understand you're new at this, and that's totally fine, but you absolutely must read the instructions on how to use any given command. If you don't you'll eventually break something in a huge way by accident. `DROP TABLE` does not ask if you're sure, it just does it, and the consequences of casually doing that on the wrong server can be severe. Be careful, be informed, and you'll be fine.

Comment: after 1.9 i want it to be 2.0

Comment: Okay thanks i'll read the manual for commands

Comment: MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature increments in units of 1. If you can simply pretend that `11` is `1.1` for the purposes of your application you'l be in better shape here. Doing this with a non-standard type is going to involve a lot of overhead that will be fussy to get right. Doing something like `x/10` when displaying it is easy. Getting this to increment by `0.1` each time is tricky.

Comment: Doing this is a terrible idea for two reasons: 1) you have a multi-part id, which violates good normalization practices (stuff you're supposed to follow when making a database), and 2) you want to assign based on ordering: there is no such thing as ordering in a table in SQL.  What you have is two related, separate, natural IDs (category/subcategory?  heading/option?), which should be stored in separate columns.  The values should likely also be written specifically during data load, not assigned by the table, since you seem to care what they are...

Comment: I have dropped the idea of using this decimal in id. Now working forward. Thanks to all for replies and helping me judging the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

The operations you must perform are two:

The first is a `DDL` operation, so you can add ID field (I suppose you haven't it when your table was born).

So you can write as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE content_details
ADD id decimal(4,2)
```

So the second operation is a `DML` script about the filling of your field, as follow:

```
UPDATE content_details
SET id = 1 + 
COALESCE(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM content_details c2
WHERE c2.contents > content_details.contents),0) * 0.1
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause you have will yield different results from what the OP wants, given `non-vegetarian` will sort before `vegetarian`.  It's attempting to order by unrelated contents, which would have all sorts of duplicate-key errors, never mind the logical disconnect.  If the OP needs values like this, it's quite probable the data should be specifically assigned, and not autogenerated.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: You're right but if I read the question, I read an ALTER TABLE so I suppose that field is added after the table creation. So I write a generic update about id field filling. If our OP in more exaustive on his request, I can tune my solution better. I've changed the < with >